# Assign name or id in Mat-Icon Angular 7

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I would like get some value in mat-icon and compare with "campaign_id"

I have two icon, one to play and the other to pause, when I click on one the another appears

in my html we have ...

```
<tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns">
    <td>{{ campaign.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.nome_campanha }}</td>
    <td>            
       <label [ngClass]="status[campaign.status].color">{{ status[campaign.status].description }}</label>
    </td>
    <td> 
       <mat-icon id="row-click" matTooltip="Ativar campanha" (click)="occurrence(1, campaign, _icon)" #_icon>play_circle_outline</mat-icon>
       <mat-icon id="row-click" matTooltip="Pausar de campanhas" (click)="occurrence(2, campaign)" *ngIf="run == 1 || run == campaign.id">pause</mat-icon>
    </td>  
</tr>
```

and in TS we have for ex

```
occurrence(e, campaign, i) {
  if(user.id == icon.id//icon.name) 
     if(icon.play == show)
       icon.play == hidde
}
```

this shoud be the logic
click on play or pause icon

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: When I click in play, the play hidde and show pause, when click in pause, pause hidde and play show, but now, I'm clicking in one icon and everyone changes, understand friend ?

Comment: I want click on play and pause of user 1, and have action only user 1

Answer (score 0):

since you are in a `*ngFor` ;ID( `id="row-click` and `#_icon`) would be same for all the `<mat-icon>`,  So instead to in-order to resolve this you need to use and index and assign that index to `<mat-icon>`

eg:

```
<tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns;index=i">
    <td>{{ campaign.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.nome_campanha }}</td>
    <td>            
       <label [ngClass]="status[campaign.status].color">{{ status[campaign.status].description }}</label>
    </td>
    <td> 
       <mat-icon [id]="'row-click-' + i" matTooltip="Ativar campanha" (click)="occurrence(1, campaign, _icon)" #_icon>play_circle_outline</mat-icon>
       <mat-icon [id]="'row-click-' + i" matTooltip="Pausar de campanhas" (click)="occurrence(2, campaign)" *ngIf="run == 1 || run == campaign.id">pause</mat-icon>
    </td>  
</tr>
```

Comment: It should be `[id]="'row-click-' + i"` instead of `id="row-click"+i`

Comment: ok, but now, how to click in icon play and hidde only this icon on this row and show icon pause only this row ?